# How to submit a new post?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi everyone so I am making an application for hosting events and when I try to add and event the submit button doesn't do anything. Please help me.

**THIS IS THE HANDLE SUBMIT FUNCTION**

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const errors = this.validate();
  this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
  if (errors) return;

  this.doSubmit();
};
```

**THIS IS THE BUTTON**

```
    renderButton(label) {
        return (
          <button disabled={this.validate()} className="btn btn-primary">
            {label}
          </button>
        );
      }
```

**THIS IS THE THE EVENTFORM**

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./form";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import { getEvent, saveEvent } from "../services/fakeEvents";
import { getCategories } from "../services/fakeCategories";

class EventForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: {
      title: "",
      eventPicture: "",
      categoryId: "",
      eventTime: "",
      numberOfAtendies: "",
      location: "",
      details: ""
    },
    categories: [],
    errors: {}
  };
  schema = {
    _id: Joi.string(),
    title: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Event Title"),
    categoryId: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Choose Category"),
    eventTime: Joi.number()
      .required()
      .label("Choose Event Time"),
    numberOfAtendies: Joi.number()
      .required()
      .min(1)
      .max(100000)
      .label("Numeber of Attendies"),
    location: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Event Location"),
    details: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Event Details")
      .min(250)
      .max(300)
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const categories = getCategories();
    this.setState({ categories });

    const eventId = this.props.match.params.id;
    if (eventId === undefined) return;

    const event = getEvent(eventId);
    if (!event) return this.props.history.replace("/not-found");

    this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(event) });
  }

  mapToViewModel(event) {
    return {
      _id: event._id,
      title: event.title,
      categoryId: event.category._id,
      eventTime: event.eventTime,
      numberOfAtendies: event.numberOfAtendies,
      location: event.location,
      details: event.details
    };
  }
  doSubmit = () => {
    saveEvent(this.state.data);

    this.props.history.push("/home");
    console.log(this.state)
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Create Event</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.renderInput("title", "Title")}
          {this.renderSelect("categoryId", "Category", this.state.categories)}
          {this.renderInput("eventTime", "Event Time")}
          {this.renderInput("numberOfAtendies", "Number of Attendies")}
          {this.renderInput("location", "Location")}
          {this.renderInput("details", "Details")}
          {this.renderButton("Create")}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EventForm;
```

Not sure if this makes sense I'm new to this so please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: Its hard to find whats wrong, the logic of validate() is mossing, please simplify your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here, it should be something like this :

```
renderButton(label) {
        return (
          <button disabled={this.validate() ? true : false} className="btn btn-primary">
            {label}
          </button>
        );
      }
```